# How to add Swipe Right Select Option in SWTableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've implemented `SWTableViewCell` successfully and added three `rightUtilityButtons` and gave the trigger via `didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex` delegate method.
Now what I want is just like the Mail app in iPhone which if you swipe right it delete the mail. How to do that with or `SWTableViewCell`?

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/swipeable-uitableviewcell-tutorial/ check this...

Comment: @seggy I've done this part. I need swipe to select the last option just like in Mail app you swipe right to trash email.

Comment: @talha I think this is what you are looking for https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

Comment: @AdeelMiraj yup! Thank You.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell) is what you are looking for. In the demo projects just follow the **MailAppDemo**. You can use this class with both xib files and storyboard prototype cells.